# Element Autoscroll for Twitter

Tags: jquery, twitter, autoscroll

I'm trying to do the following:

I have a webpage that plays my twitter timeline like this

[Twitter without Scroll](http://wildenmedia.com/twitter/static/)

What I'm trying to do is to add an auto scroll that scrolls to the bottom of the timeline then goes up again.

I was able to get the following code to scroll on the page but not the element.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Twitter Feed</title>

<style>
html{
 overflow:hidden !important;
}
body{
 background-color:#333;
}
#container{
 width:350px;
}
div.timeline div.stream{
 overflow:hidden !important;
 overflow-x:hidden !important;
 overflow-y:hidden !important;
}
div.twtr-doc{
 margin-top: 37px;
}
</style>
<script src="jsFiles/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
function scroll(speed) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() }, speed, function() {
        $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
    });
}

speed = 1000;

scroll(speed)
setInterval(function(){scroll(speed)}, speed * 1);
</script>


<div id="container">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/wildenmediainc" data-widget-id="539490745749475328" data-chrome="noscrollbar nofooter" width="350px;">Tweets by @wildenmediainc  </a>
 <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The result is here [Twitter with Scroll](http://wildenmedia.com/twitter/withScroll/)

Now this is not really what I'm looking for. What I want is to get the scroll to happen inside the twitter timeline. Please help me get there.

I'm not a coder but with your help I can do it maybe

Thanks,
Hussein

Comment: The problem is that the Twitter plugin is a iframe that you can't alter so easily. You need to inject JavaScript into the header of the iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response

I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Take a look in the developer tool in your browser and if you look at the DOM you will see that the Twitter plugin is inside a iframe.

Comment: Hello Zorken17 

Thanks but I tried everything with iframe and it is still not working

Can you be more specific

I just tried the following 

I replaced 



    function scroll(speed) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() },    speed, function() {
        $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
       });
    }

WITH

function scroll(speed) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")).offset().top }, speed, function() {
        $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
    });
}

Comment: That's what I am trying to say, it is very hard. You need to wait for $(window).load then you need to target the iframe head $('iframe head').append(your css code) and hope it will work.

Comment: the Element that has the total height of all feed is an Ordered List ol and it has a class name of "h-feed"

I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: It is working now by targeting the iframe 
function scroll(speed) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")).height() - $(window).height() }, speed, function() {
        $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
    });
}

but it is not scrolling the full height of the feed. 
I the ol has the total height but I wasn't able to call the ol